# Sorting list of lists based on another list of lists

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.x

I have a list of lists that I want to sort in the same order as another list of lists:

```
l1 = [['hello', 'test'], ['there', 'correct'], ['Elem3', 'yes']]

l2 = [['hello'], ['Elem3'], ['there']]
```

So I want to rearrange l1 so it's in the same order as l2 . (Note: This is just a simple test case. The actual list I'm dealing with has several elements in it.

e.g. the result should be:

```
l1 = [['hello', 'test'], ['Elem3', 'yes'], ['there', 'correct']]
```

Using python2 (enterprise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use python's built-in `sort`:

```
l1.sort(key=lambda pair: l2.index(pair[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very pretty or efficient but I assume those are not the requirements:

```
>>> l3 = [None] * len(l2)
>>> for item in l1:
...     l3[l2.index([item[0]])] = item
>>> print l3
[['hello', 'test'], ['Elem3', 'yes'], ['there', 'correct']]
```